# Handle elastic search failure - How do I sync records in Dynamodb and Elastic Search ?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-elasticsearch

I am using AWS Dynamo DB and Elastic Search. I am looking for some way to keep Dynamo DB data in sync with Elastic Search if any of them fails.

Currently I use lambda to push my record into Elastic Search. I know there is plugin - Logstash available but I can't use that as it will require a lot of changes. 
Also, I won't prefer scanning the DynamoDB table, as it is too expensive. Is there any other way I could achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of SQS. Move failed records to SQS and later you can schedule a lambda to read records from SQS and send the records to ElasticSearch.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to go with the plugin solution, you can continue with a lambda but triggered by DynamoDb Streams. In this way you shouldn't have to scan the table since the stream will have the added item and you can reuse the part of sending it to ES.

Take a look at [DynamoDB Streams and Lambda triggers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.html).

Comment: I have lambda triggered by streams. This is a case when Elastic Search/Dynamodb is down. How do I push changes that weren't synced ?